# Not able to get selected option using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Working on getting the selected option of a select tag using Angular JS. I'm getting the attribute value as "1,2..", What I need is "one,two.. when I change the select tag.

My sample code is

### JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($timeout, $scope) {
$scope.countList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'One' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Two' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Three' }
];
$scope.countSelected = $scope.countList[0].id;    
alert('Selected count ID: ' + $scope.countSelected);

    $scope.onchange = function(id) {
    alert("id:"+id);
    }
});
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
Count:
<select ng-model="countSelected" 
        ng-options="count.id as count.name for count in countList" ng-change="onchange(countSelected)">
</select>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXJE6/6/).

Answer (score 8):

Try this one

http://jsfiddle.net/TXJE6/8/

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Count:
    <select ng-model="countSelected" 
    ng-options="count.id as count.name for count in countList" ng-change="onchange(countList[countSelected-1])">
    </select>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($timeout, $scope) {
    $scope.countList = [
        { id: 1, name: 'One' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Two' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Three' }
    ];
    $scope.countSelected = $scope.countList[0].id;    
    alert('Selected count ID: ' + $scope.countSelected);

    $scope.onchange = function(id) {
        alert("id:"+id.name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -8):

just bind jquery change on the drop down list when you call the controller or when promise finish loading data like this

```
 $('#ddl').change(function () {
            console.log($('#ddl option:selected').val());
 });
```

Comment: Better to use existing Angular features instead of using Jquery workaround.