# How to get "selected : true" from arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Hi I want to know how to get ID's of selected array.
I have collection around 100 of arrays. I have checkbox and some of checked arrays. They have property "selected : true" but i cant print it out. I tryied many combinations but still doesnt work.

```
$scope.Sel = [$scope.myText.Selected];
var test = $scope.myText.Selected.id;
var test  = $scope.myText.Selected;

etc.
```

Comment: `selected` is not the same as `Selected`.

Comment: I tried every combination ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877332/not-able-to-get-selected-option-using-angular-js

Comment: Show a portion of the array... What is `$scope.myText`?

Comment: MyText including ...[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Simon",
    "surname": "Wiggins",
    "pesel": "1692113016999",
    "gender": "male"
  },
 etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) to filter out selected items from an array. You would need to inject `$filter` in your controller in order to do so.

Something like this:

```
$scope.selectedItems = $filter('filter')($scope.array, function(item){
    return item.selected === true;
});
// $scope.selectedItems would contain only the selected items from $scope.array
```